# Radio Button POST issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, radio-button

So here is the issue. I am running a mysql query and throwing the results of that query into radio buttons with a while statement. The amount of radio buttons can vary, so I can't do a set number of them with the POST function. I'm struggling with making it so that the user can select one of the rows and then the "serverId" data from the query is passed on to the test.php page. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Server Information</title>
 </head>
 <body>

<?php

//Starts the session and grabs the username from it
session_start();
$name=mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);

include 'header.php';
include 'mysql_connect.php';

mysql_select_db('ist421test');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT userName, dateCreated, serverName, serverId, publicDNS, isRunning FROM server_tbl WHERE userName='$name' ORDER BY dateCreated DESC") or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0): ?>
<form method="post" name="server_information" id="server_information" action="test.php">
<label>Server Information</label><br><br>
<table border='1'>
<tr>
    <th>Selection</th>
    <th>User Name</th>
    <th>Date Created</th>
    <th>Server Name</th>
    <th>Server Id</th>
    <th>Public DNS</th>
    <th>Running</th>
</tr>
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
<tr>
    <td><input method="post" type="radio" name="server" value="server_information" action="test.php"></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['userName']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['dateCreated']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['serverName']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['serverId']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['publicDNS'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['isRunning']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="server_stop" value="Stop Server"/>
<input type="submit" name="server_terminate" value="Terminate Server"/>
</form>
<?php endif; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, a couple of recommendations.

First, for the radio input delete "server_information" from the value tag and paste in your serverID echo. For example.

```
<input type="radio" name="server" value="<?php echo $row['serverId']; ?>" />
```

Notice the `method` and `action` attributes have been removed. They're only applicable for `form` elements.

Give that a go now. Only one radio button should be selectable, and only one Server ID should be POST'ed to your form.

You can access the POST'ed variable on `test.php` using `$_POST['server']`.

Comment: This only makes it display the radio buttons in the field, but due to the quotation marks around the php commands it doesn't display the record anymore just blank space. Any ideas.

Comment: Can you view the page source in your browser and paste the code that it's producing? (perhaps update your question above)

Comment: I was wrong. I apologize. It is actually displaying the radio button in the serverid field and pushing the data from serverid into the next field over. But it does work fine now, just that it doesn't display the serverid in the same field as the radio button....

Comment: Ok, that sounds easy then. Just re-arrange the data in the `<td>` cells into the right places.

Comment: Thanks. Got it all sorted.